# ISODate in MongoDB without time

Tags: mongodb, isodate

I was wondering if there is a way to change the ISODate format in MongoDB (from the shell of through pymongo) to show only the date and not the time. My actual collection (example) has the following structure.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5dde89f8d93f9eca2f7aa135"),
        "worker_id" : "WORK_1",
        "gender" : "M",
        "birth" : ISODate("1970-06-08T00:00:00Z"),
        "job" : {
                "att" : [
                        {
                                "employer_id" : "EMPL_2",
                                "date" : ISODate("1990-05-05T00:00:00Z"),
                                "job_type" : "Att"
                        },
                        {
                                "employer_id" : "EMPL_1",
                                "date" : ISODate("1993-11-24T00:00:00Z"),
                                "job_type" : "Att"
                        }
                ],
                "mis" : [
                        {
                                "employer_id" : "EMPL_1",
                                "date" : ISODate("1991-12-01T00:00:00Z"),
                                "job_type" : "Mis"
                        }
                ]
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5dde89f8d93f9eca2f7aa136"),
        "worker_id" : "WORK_2",
        "gender" : "F",
        "birth" : ISODate("1988-08-22T00:00:00Z"),
        "job" : {
                "att" : [
                        {
                                "employer_id" : "EMPL_3",
                                "date" : ISODate("1995-08-30T00:00:00Z"),
                                "job_type" : "Att"
                        },
                        {
                                "employer_id" : "EMPL_3",
                                "date" : ISODate("1994-03-28T00:00:00Z"),
                                "job_type" : "Att"
                        }
                ],
                "mis" : [
                        {
                                "employer_id" : "EMPL_3",
                                "date" : ISODate("1992-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                                "job_type" : "Mis"
                        }
                ]
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5dde89f8d93f9eca2f7aa137"),
        "worker_id" : "WORK_3",
        "gender" : "F",
        "birth" : ISODate("1978-05-24T00:00:00Z"),
        "job" : {
                "att" : null,
                "mis" : [
                        {
                                "employer_id" : "EMPL_1",
                                "date" : ISODate("1995-04-25T00:00:00Z"),
                                "job_type" : "Mis"
                        }
                ]
        }
}
```

Originally I had string data in the format '%Y-%m-%d' (es. '1990-05-05'). 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense to keep dates in ISODate format; you just need a small amount of care adding and extracting the date.

Use `datetime.datetime.combine()` to strip off the time component when adding data, and `datetime.date()` to convert it back into a date.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime

db = MongoClient()["mydatabase"]

def utc_midnight(d: datetime.date) -> datetime.datetime:
    return datetime.datetime.combine(d, datetime.time(0, 0))

db.testcollection.insert_one(
    {
        "worker_id": "WORK_1",
        "gender": "M",
        "birth": utc_midnight(datetime.date(1970, 6, 8)),
        "job": {
            "att": [
                {
                    "employer_id": "EMPL_2",
                    "date": utc_midnight(datetime.date(1990, 5, 5)),
                    "job_type": "Att"
                },
                {
                    "employer_id": "EMPL_1",
                    "date": utc_midnight(datetime.date(1993, 11, 24)),
                    "job_type": "Att"
                }
            ],
            "mis": [
                {
                    "employer_id": "EMPL_1",
                    "date": utc_midnight(datetime.date(1991, 12, 1)),
                    "job_type": "Mis"
                }
            ]
        }
    })


record = db.testcollection.find_one()
birth_date = record['birth'].date()
print(birth_date.year)
print(birth_date.month)
print(birth_date.day)
```

gives

```
1970
6
8
```